# SQL Group by. Add new row with average result for all groups

Tags: sql

I am working with a table where I have the income for each citizen in a region and I want to be able to look up two things with one query (ideally):

1. Average income for each region
2. Average income for all regions.

To accomplish the first I would do a group by:

```
select avg(income),region,count(*) as population_size from income_region group by region
```

However the above does not display the average income across all regions. And I can't sum up the average income since the population size in each region differs.  To do that I would need to also create the following query:

```
select avg(income),count(*) as population_size from income_region
```

Is there a way to to get the latter query into the first query and name it as "All" instead of the name of the region.

Comment: You can use `rollup` - which DBMS product are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use union all

```
select avg(income),region,count(*) as population_size
from income_region group by region
union all
select avg(income),'',count(*) as population_size from income_region
```

Answer (score 0):

Most databases support with `rollup` or `grouping sets`:

```
select region, avg(income), count(*) as population_size
from income_region
group by region with rollup;
```

Or:

```
select region, avg(income), count(*) as population_size
from income_region
group by grouping sets ( (region), () );
```