# SQL: Calculate total average values for different variations of groups

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with a table that has the following information for 20 different years

1. Income for citizens for a given year
2. Region which shows where the citizens live
3. Year which represents the income of the citizen in the current year

I am using a group by function in order to get average income level for each group,year. And recently I got help here ([SQL Group by. Add new row with average result for all groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54861399/sql-group-by-add-new-row-with-average-result-for-all-groups/54861417#54861417))
so I could add an extra row with avg income for all regions.

```
select avg(income),region,year,count(*) as population_size
from income_region group by region,year
union all
select avg(income),'All','All',count(*) as population_size from income_region
```

However, when I add in an extra column "year" to the group and try the "union all" solution for both year and region it only calculates the average income for all years and all regions.

Ideally I would also have the following types of new groups:

- Average income when `year = 2001`
- Average income when `year = 2002'` ...etc (for all years)
- Average income for all years when `region = 'North America'`
- Average income for all years when `region = 'Europe'`.. etc. (for all regions)

How can be this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `with rollup`:

```
select region, year, count(*) as population_size, avg(income)
from income_region
group by region with rollup;
```

You can refer to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) for more details.

Comment: Hello sorry I wrote wrong in the initially OP. I meant to write "group by year, region" rather than just region. Writing "group by region,year with rollup " does not give the desired result as it only creates Null for region when year is also Null.

Answer (score 0):

just use rollup

```
select avg(income),region,year,count(*) as population_size
from income_region group by region with rollup
```

Comment: Hello sorry I wrote wrong in the initially OP. I meant to write "group by year, region" rather than just region